# Where is the source code of the Postgres txid_current function?

Tags: postgresql

Where is the source code of the Postgres txid_current function? ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-TXID-SNAPSHOT))
I want to read the function to better understand how it handles values bigger than (2^64)/2.

Comment: Don't worry, you'll never exhaust 2^63 in a million years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[include/catalog/pg_proc.dat](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/include/catalog/pg_proc.dat#L9519-L9521) maps `txid_current` to [src/backend/utils/adt/xid8funcs.c:pg_current_xact_id](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/4c04be9b05ad2ec5acd27c3417bf075c13cab134/src/backend/utils/adt/xid8funcs.c#L358) which leads the majority of the implementation in [GetTopFullTransactionId](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/4c04be9b05ad2ec5acd27c3417bf075c13cab134/src/backend/access/transam/xact.c#L451) and deeper it goes, but easy to follow.